# (Angular) Retain data on browser refresh

Tags: angular

I need a way to retain my data even when I refresh my browser. I have used rxjs behaviour subject but still not helping

Using local/session storage is not prefered as it's not safe and better practice especially with important data

Comment: Angular Rerender the data in every time you refresh so you couldn't do that, so kindly use local storage or cookies for that concept.

Comment: what is the nature of data that you are trying to retain? I am asking this question cos of the last comment. if you are encrypting the data, I wonder why would you not use local storage. Also, once you have retrieved the data you can delete your local storage object in case you don`t want it to be used further. Store the data before every refresh in local storage and delete it once you are done with the retrieval.

Comment: which kind of data it is. i mean are u using forms??

Comment: I'm getting the data from back-end api. The data is user's information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A BehaviourSubject is memory only and will not survive a browser refresh, you need to put it in session storage.

Have a look at my state management library RxCache, it has options to use session storage. It will take care of the persisting to session storage if you set the sessionStorage flag to true.

https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-rxcache